# ¿Como Establecer cambios en activity dentro de un botón antes de que se ejecute un método?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Estoy ejecutando un metodo en un setOnClickListener pero quiero mostrar un ProgressBar y hacer cambios en textView inmediatamente cuando se da clic en el botón, pero lo hace al finalizar el método, ¿que puedo hacer?
este esmi codigo

```
         public void onClick(View v) {
             titulo.setText("Enviando..");
             contenido.setText("Enviando registro...");
             progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
             bandera = "true";
             AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
                 @Override
                 public void run() {
                     enviar(position, nombre, email, telefonoCelular, telefonoCasa, facebook, twitter, observaciones, nombreFoto, DirFotoCredencialLocal, DirFotoCredencial);

                 }
             });
         }
```

Comment: Lo que deseas es ver que los TextView cambian su texto y posteriormente realizar el proceso?

Comment: No estoy seguro, pero según la doc de AsyncTask, el método execute corre en el hilo principal, por lo que la operación puede ser costosa y la UI quede congelada esperando a que acabe el proceso... si ese es el caso, deberías realizar tu operación en un hilo secundario.  Una forma sencilla de gestionarlo es con corrutinas.

Comment: Usando Asynctask  se pueden ejecutar operaciones en segundo plano y mostrar los resultados en el hilo principal @ManuelMato , claro lo de hoy y con un "boost" mayor son las corrutinas sin duda!.

Comment: Sabía que la clase AsyncTask corre en segundo plano, lo que no entiendo es el @MainThread del execute -.- graaacias :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te recomiendo extender de la clase AsyncTask y hacer los cambios que necesitas en el método onPreExecute.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    new SenderTask().execute();
}

private class SenderTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer> {

protected void onPreExecute(){
    titulo.setText("Enviando..");
    contenido.setText("Enviando registro...");
    progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    bandera = "true";
}

 
protected Integer doInBackground(Void... voids) {
    enviar(position, nombre, email, telefonoCelular, telefonoCasa, facebook, twitter, observaciones, nombreFoto, DirFotoCredencialLocal, DirFotoCredencial);
    return 0;//Retorna un código indicando si el proceso fue exitoso o no
}
protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
    //Se llama a este callback cuando la tarea ha sido completada
    progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

Espero que te sirva

Comment: Gracias Amigo, lo resolví de otra manera pero esto me sirve para otro activity

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias a todos, al final me sirvió mas preguntar al usuario con un Alert si desea enviar el registro desde una pantalla anterior, para cuando se crea mi activity EnviarDatos poner directamente en el onCreate mi codigo del método que envía los datos dentro de un Thread,al igual que un método donde se ejecuta el progreso del ProgressBar.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_enviar_datos);

         titulo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.titulo_enviardatos);
         contenido = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.contenido);
         mProgress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);

         
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                enviar(position,nombre, email, telefonoCelular, telefonoCasa, facebook, twitter, observaciones,  nombreFoto , DirFotoCredencialLocal, DirFotoCredencial);
                doWork();
            }
        }).start();
      }

    private void doWork() {
        int progress;
        for ( progress=0; progress<100; progress+=10) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(4000);
                mProgress.setProgress(progress);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                // Timber.e(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        if(progress >= 100){
          
                    Intent intent1 = new Intent(EnviarDatos.this, HomeActivityDB.class);
                    bandera="true";
                    intent1.putExtra("bandera", bandera);
                    startActivity(intent1);
        }
    }
```